# Where to store file for email attachment in Java

Tags: java, relative-path, filepath, email-attachments

In my Java webapp I have an automated script that sends out an email and in this email I need to attach a file. I currently have it in a public "assets" folder however I am unable to pass in the file path in my Java code without using an absolute path (my dev server is my local workstation so the paths are completely different from this to live).

Is there a way to attach the file using a web url (http://domain.com/assets/file.pdf) or a relative path? My current working directory according to Java is "C:\Users\USERNAME\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\domains\domain1\" but there is nothing useful at that path apparently - no Java classes, no web files, nothing. Or should I put the file somewhere else.. like in the same folder as the script that sends out the email, which seems wrong.

Comment: If I udnerstand your problem correctly: the file you want to attach needs to be in your classpath, so make sure that the folder the file is in is also included in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on your deployment.

As @Jakub said: if you can arrange for the file to be on your application's classpath, you can use ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(...) to retrieve your file contents (the javadoc is reasonably good; it's helpful to know that you can get a classloader using this.getClass().getClassloader()).

You can use a configuration file (and any of the good configuration management libraries) to specify the absolute path to your resource file.

If you know where the file is relative to your execution path, you can say "new File("").getAbsolutePath()", then append your relative path.

Comment: So if my package is org.orgname.project I should put the pdf file in a directory like org.orgname.project.lib? And then if I want to attach the pdf to the email do String filename = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/lib/filename.pdf").getPath()? (If this is right then it still doesn't work - nullPointerException still)

Comment: if you store your directory in org.orgname.project.lib, then your resource path is "org/orgname/project/lib/filename.pdf"

Comment: On a style note, chaining after .getResource is just asking for a null-pointer exception. Get the resource, check for null, and then if it's NOT null, getPath() or get the contents.